# jquery remove last span in series matching ID

Tags: jquery

How would I obtain the text value of the last span in a series in order to remove that span and all its contents?

In this example, it is the "Chrysler" span that's considered the last span in the series, not the "delete" span.

```
<span id="maketags" style="">
    <span class="make">
        Ford
        <span class="delete">delete</span>
    </span>

    <span class="make">
        Chevy
        <span class="delete">delete</span>
    </span>

    <span class="make">
        Chrysler
        <span class="delete">delete</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Currently, I know I'm close with this but its returning "delete" (I know why, I just can't figure out the correct way to do this)

```
var lastMake = $('#maketags span:last').html();
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

My fault for not being more clear. I needed assistance matching the last element. I shouldn't have added the bit about the goal, because I already knew how to remove it. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to match what you want to match

To match the last span being a child of `#maketags`:

```
var lastMake = $('#maketags > span:last');
```

(`.html()` returns the HTML inside the matched element).

The proof is here: [jsfiddle.net/tadeck/5Lm3T/](http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/5Lm3T/)

### How to delete what you matched

Just so this answer is comprehensive, to remove what you matched, just use `.remove()` (or, if you want to use removed element later with assigned events, use `.detach()`):

```
lastMake.remove();
```

Comment: OP is already matching the last element, and is asking how to *remove* it once it is matched.

Comment: @Jim: The OP wants to match the whole element matched within my answer. OP says: "_The goal is to remove the "Chrysler" span **and** the "delete" span contained within it._" and "_I know I'm close with this **but** its returning "delete"_". Which means the selector is wrong - it matches the element contained within the element OP wants to remove. This is something totally opposite to what you are saying.

Comment: Tadeck is correct. His answer came in first so marked his answer as correct.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked the double span

Answer (score 2):

> *"The goal is to remove the "Chrysler" span and the "delete" span contained within it."*

If you want to remove it, you need to use `.remove()`. To target an element by its class, use a class selector.

```
$('#maketags .make').last().remove();
```

- [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [`class-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

---

If you wanted to keep the `.make`, and only remove its content, use `.empty()`.

```
$('#maketags .make').last().empty();
```

- [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

---

Note that I used `.last()` instead of the `:last` selector.

As stated in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)...

> Because `:last` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:last` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `$('.make:last').remove()​`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtvamp/AAMRb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    $('#maketags span:last').remove(true);
```

It depends what exactly you want to do. The remove() will remove not only the html but also all the events liceners of this span. If you just want to remove the html you can simply use the remove(false).

If you want a better solution for a fadeOut or an effect on removing and you use jquery 1.6 or later you can use the promise function:

```
    $('#maketags span:last').fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function() {
            $this->remove(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are (likely) selecting the correct element. You are simply not performing a delete action on it. To do that, use jQuery's remove function.

Change this

```
var lastMake = $('#maketags span:last').html();
```

to this

```
var lastMake = $('#maketags span:last').remove();
```

It's not really necessary to assign it to a variable, but you may find it useful to know that all such jQuery function return a jQuery object (so `lastMake` will contain the object you've removed).

Comment: OP clearly said that "_The goal is to remove the "Chrysler" span and the "delete" span contained within it._". Your answer says nothing about how to match the correct element, it still matches incorrect one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the operator >

```
$('#maketags > span:last').html()
```

if you dont use it, it will get the latest span in #maketags. and it is delete span in the crsyler's span.